# Como usar o atributo Oninput?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou relembrando algumas coisas no HTML e me deparei com o atributo Oninput. Sei que esse atributo serve para fazer cálculos, mas não sei usar.

Answer (score 3):

O `OnInput` não é um elemento e sim um atributo/evento que dispara quando o usuário digita algo dentro de um elemento (pode ser o elemento `<input>`).

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" oninput="minhaFuncao()">
```

O código acima executa `minhaFuncao()` quando alguém escreve algo nele.

Outro detalhe é que para criar uma função pra ser usada no elemento, você deve estudar JavaScript ou jQuery.

Comment: Sei que é um atributo, erro meu. Valeu pela resposta.

Answer (score -1):

`oninput` é uma maneira não recomendada de adicionar ouvinte de evento ao evento `input`. `addEventListener` é uma maneira preferível. O evento em si ocorre quando o valor é alterado. É um dos três eventos comumente usados para entrada do usuário.

[image: demonstração]

```js
// on every value change
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  console.log("input:", e.target.value)
})

// on blur if value was changed
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  console.log("change:", e.target.value)
})

// on every blur
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
  console.log("blur:", e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input>
```

```js
// on every value change
document.querySelector("input").oninput = function (e) {
  console.log("input:", e.target.value)
}

// on blur if value was changed
document.querySelector("input").onchange = function (e) {
  console.log("change:", e.target.value)
}

// on every blur
document.querySelector("input").onblur = function (e) {
  console.log("blur:", e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input>
```

```js
function onEveryValueChange(e) {
  console.log("input:", e.target.value)
}

function onBlurIfValueWasChanged(e) {
  console.log("change:", e.target.value)
}

function onEveryBlur(e) {
  console.log("blur:", e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input
  oninput="onEveryValueChange(event)"
  onchange="onBlurIfValueWasChanged(event)"
  onblur="onEveryBlur(event)"
/>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que fez e qual é a relação do seu código com o atributo `oninput`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ok

Comment: Mas por que não é recomendado utilizá-lo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, como o elemento pode ter apenas um ouvinte do evento `input` adicionado via `oninput` e, no caso de adicioná-lo em html, o manipulador deve ser uma função global. Também addEventListener é mais flexível.